# unable to install certbot on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ssl, https, ubuntu-16.04, certbot

I tried installing **certbot** by following the installation guide
on the official [Certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/#ubuntuxenial-other) site.

Unfortunately I am not able to install following packages

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo apt-get install certbot
```

[image: error]

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-70-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-70-generic but it is not going to be installed
linux-image-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-70-generic but it is not going to be installed
linux-signed-image-4.4.0-70-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-70-generic (= 4.4.0-70.91) but it is not going to be installed
software-properties-common : Depends: python3-software-properties (= 0.96.20.7) aber 0.96.20.4 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems
```

my current kernel version is

```
4.4.0-63-generic
```

Approaches to solve this issue:

- cleaned up /boot - no effect
- tried sudo apt-get -f install  - no effect

**UPDATE:**

I finally came to a **solution** by myself.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Comment: I down-vote. Please go to the UBUNTU forum for such question.

Answer (score 2):

I use Ubuntu16.04 + nginx + Certbot

Use this approach:

Ubuntu includes the Certbot client in their default repository, but it's a bit out of date. Instead, try it from Certbot's official Ubuntu PPA, or Personal Package Archive. These are alternative repositories that package more recent or more obscure software. First, add the repository:

**$sudo add-apt-repository ppa:certbot/certbot**

You'll need to press ENTER to accept. Afterwards, update the package list to pick up the new repository's package information:

**$sudo apt-get update**

And finally, install the certbot package:

**$sudo apt-get install certbot**